# Custom email validation regex pattern not working properly

Tags: regex, validation, email

So I've got [/.+[^\x20-\x2A\x2C\x2F\x3A-\x40\x5B-\x5E\x60\x7B-\xFF]\@[\w+-?]+(.{1})\w{2,}/](https://regex101.com/r/iX5zB5/1) pattern I want to use for email validation on client-side, which doesn't work as expected.

I know that my pattern is simple and doesn't cover every [standard possibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax), but it's part of my regex training.

Local part of address should be valid only when it has at least one digit [0-9] or letter [a-zA-Z] and can be mixed with comma or plus sign or underscore (or all at once) and then *@* sign, then domain part, but no IP address literals, only domain names with at least one letter or digit, followed by one dot and at least two letters or two digits.

In test string form it **doesn't validate** *a@b.com* and **does validate** *baz_bar.test+private@e-mail-testing-service..com*, which is wrong - it should be vice versa - validate *a@b.com* and not validate *baz_bar.test+private@e-mail-testing-service..com*

What specific error I've got there and where?
I can't locate this, sorry..

Comment: Is it good to you? https://regex101.com/r/iX5zB5/2

Comment: Thanks @JorgeCampos, it works. :)

Comment: I will add as an answer.

Comment: @Jorge Your expression validates things like ",@b.com" Is that really what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You're requiring the local part (before @) to be *at least* two characters with the `.+` followed by the character class `[^...]`. It's looking for *any* character followed by *another* character not in the list of exclusions you specify. That explains why "a@b.com" doesn't match.

The second problem is partly caused by the character class range `+-?` which includes the `.` character. I think you wanted `[-\w+?]+`. (Do you really want question marks?) And then later I think you wanted to look for a literal `.` character but it really ends up matching the first character that didn't match the previous block.

Between the regex provided and the explanatory text I'm not sure what rules you intend to implement though. And since this is an exercise it's probably better to just give hints anyway.

You will also want to use the `^` and `$` anchors to makes sure the entire string matches.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your regex

```
From: .+[^\x20-\x2A\x2C\x2F\x3A-\x40\x5B-\x5E\x60\x7B-\xFF]\@[\w+-?]+(\.{1})\w{2,}
  To: .+[^\x20-\x2A\x2C\x2F\x3A-\x40\x5B-\x5E\x60\x7B-\xFF]?\@[\w+-]+(\.{1})\w{2,}
```

Notice that I added a `?` before the `@` sign and removed the `?` from the first "group" after the `@` sign. Adding that `?` will make your regex to know that hole "group" is not mandatory.

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/iX5zB5/2